# jQuery manipulation / each() - why is this not targeting individual elements?

Tags: jquery, foreach

I have some images (generated elsewhere), that I want to manipulate and enhance using jQuery.

I have a script executing everything I need, except for individual manipulation; my script executes on all elements, not individually. What am I missing?

This is what I have:

**Multiple images in this format:**

```
<p>
  <a href="">
    <img src="" />
  </a>
</p>
<p>
  <a href="">
    <img src="" />
  </a>
</p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
  $('p').each(function(){

        //grab img's SRC
        var imgLinkMerge = $('p img').attr('src');

          //find the a tag, change HREF for imgLinkMerge value
          $(this).find('a').attr('href', imgLinkMerge).each(function(){
            //set css BG IMG
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imgLinkMerge + ')');
          });

        });
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's happening that's different from what you want?

Comment: I think var imgLinkMerge = $('p img').attr('src'); on this you might want var imgLinkMerge = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `$('p img')` you are selecting all `img` within every `p` on the page. You want to focus on **this** `p` inside the `each()` loop.

Change this:

```
var imgLinkMerge = $('p img').attr('src');
```

to this:

```
var imgLinkMerge = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
```

Comment: and declare var _this = $(this); at the beginning to reuse

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('p').each(function(){

        //grab img's SRC
        var imgLinkMerge = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

          //find the a tag, change HREF for imgLinkMerge value
          $(this).find('a').attr('href', imgLinkMerge).each(function(){
            //set css BG IMG
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imgLinkMerge + ')');
          });

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This changing

```
var imgLinkMerge = $('p img').attr('src');
```

to

```
var imgLinkMerge = $('img',$(this)).attr('src');
```

this will select `img` using the current context ie the current `p`